# Flashing screen when changing route with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a simple route system, where I have a page as a Container (`Home Page`) and inside it I have two sections (`NewPage` and `StoredPage`).

I'm leaving all the route settings in one place, which is in App.tsx. I do this to stay centralized and have better control (I don't know if I'm doing it wrong).

The problem that happens is that, when changing the section, it is blinking, for some reason it is reloading the page again.

NOTE: I use [react-router-guards](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-guards)

**APP.TSX**

```
import HomePage from 'pages/HomePage';
import StoredPage from 'pages/StoredPage';
import { memo, useMemo } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GuardedRoute, GuardProvider, Next } from 'react-router-guards';
import { GuardFunctionRouteProps, GuardToRoute } from 'react-router-guards/dist/types';

export const Main = memo(() => {
    const RequireLoginGuard = (to: GuardToRoute, from: GuardFunctionRouteProps | null, next: Next) => next();

    return (
        <ErrorBoundary instance={instance}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <GuardProvider guards={[RequireLoginGuard]} loading={() => <div>Loading Global</div>}>
                    <Switch>
                        <GuardedRoute exact path='/new' loading={() => <div>Loading New Page</div>} component={HomePage} />
                        <GuardedRoute exact path='/stored' loading={() => <div>Loading Stored Page</div>} component={HomePage} />
                        <GuardedRoute path='*' component={() => <Redirect to='/new' />} />
                    </Switch>
                </GuardProvider>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    );
});
```

**HOMEPAGE.TSX**

```
import NewPage from 'pages/NewPage';
import StoredPage from 'pages/StoredPage';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SectionTitle from 'xpi-black-ui/Common/SectionTitle';
import Navigation from '../../components/Navigation';
import MainContainer, { SectionContainer } from './styles';

const HomePage = () => {
    const navigationItems = useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                key: 'new',
                title: 'New Quotation',
                link: '/new',
                component: () => <NewPage />,
            },
            {
                key: 'stored',
                title: 'New Quotation 2',
                link: '/stored',
                component: () => <StoredPage />,
            },
        ],
        []
    );

    return (
        <MainContainer>
            <SectionContainer>Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</SectionContainer>
            <SectionContainer isSecondary>
                <SectionTitle>
                    <Navigation />

                    <div>C</div>
                </SectionTitle>

                <Switch>
                    {navigationItems.map(({ key, link, component: PageComponent }) => (
                        <Route key={key} path={link} component={PageComponent} exact />
                    ))}
                </Switch>
            </SectionContainer>
        </MainContainer>
    );
};
```

**NAVIGATION.TSX**

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavLink, { Container } from './styles';

const Navigation = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const isActive = useCallback((linkPathSelected) => pathname === linkPathSelected, [pathname]);
    const links = [
        { key: 'new', to: '/new', title: 'Criar Cotação' },
        { key: 'stored', to: '/stored', title: 'Cotações Armazenadas' },
    ];

    return (
        <Container>
            {links.map(({ key, to, title }) => (
                <NavLink exact key={key} to={to} $isActive={isActive(to)}>
                    {title}
                </NavLink>
            ))}
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, the issue is in your `Homepage` component with the way you define your `navigationItems` array's `component` properties combined with how the `Route` component treats the `component` prop when a function is passed to it.

```
const navigationItems = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      key: 'new',
      title: 'New Quotation',
      link: '/new',
      component: () => <NewPage />,    // <-- function
    },
    {
      key: 'stored',
      title: 'New Quotation 2',
      link: '/stored',
      component: () => <StoredPage />, // <-- function
    },
  ],
  []
);
```

...

```
<Switch>
  {navigationItems.map(({ key, link, component: PageComponent }) => (
    <Route
      key={key}
      path={link}
      component={PageComponent} // <-- function passed through
      exact
    />
  ))}
</Switch>
```

[Route `component`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component):

> When you use `component` (instead of `render` or `children`, below)
> the router uses [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to create a new [React
> element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) from the given component. That means if you provide an
> inline function to the component prop, you would create a new
> component every render. This results in the existing component
> unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the
> existing component. When using an inline function for inline
> rendering, use the `render` or the `children` prop (below).

The solution is to define the `navigationItems` object properties in terms of the `Route` component's props API. If you are passing components through that you want to me rendered on the `component` prop then they should be references to the React components instead of functions returning JSX.

```
const navigationItems = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      key: 'new',
      title: 'New Quotation',
      link: '/new',
      component: NewPage,
    },
    {
      key: 'stored',
      title: 'New Quotation 2',
      link: '/stored',
      component: StoredPage,
    },
  ],
  []
);
```

...

```
<Switch>
  {navigationItems.map(({ key, link, ...props }) => (
    <Route key={key} exact path={link} {...props} />
  ))}
</Switch>
```

You may want to do the same thing for the `link` property, renaming it to `path` so it aligns more with its usage.

```
const navigationItems = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      key: 'new',
      title: 'New Quotation',
      path: '/new',
      component: NewPage,
    },
    {
      key: 'stored',
      title: 'New Quotation 2',
      path: '/stored',
      component: StoredPage,
    },
  ],
  []
);
```

...

```
<Switch>
  {navigationItems.map(({ key, ...props }) => (
    <Route key={key} exact {...props} />
  ))}
</Switch>
```

Comment: I really liked your answer, I scored it. But even so, I still have the same problem. Any idea? The menu that I click to change sections is a NavLink, does it have something related?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Interesting. Ok. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox of your code above that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? I wouldn't suspect the links, but it'd be nice to see a live version like you are to see what or where any problem areas may exist.

Comment: See if you can access: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hellman-m0qnd?file=/src/components/Navigation/index.tsx

I'm on the company's pc, so the sandbox doesn't run on the intranet, I can create files anymore.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Yeah, I can access. Looks like it's missing a `HomePage` component declaration, and any navigation component.

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason the browser is crashing on this site, I posted the navigation component here in the question.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS I am unable to reproduce what I think you are describing as blinking. (https://codesandbox.io/s/flashing-screen-when-changing-route-with-reactjs-mxp5i) I'm in Chrome on a Mac. I do see what I would describe as a single flicker where the page goes blank once between page navigations (*unmount old page, blank, mount new page*), but nothing flashing. I was unable to find any `xpi-black-ui` package to import, is this a local custom package you are consuming? I also had to mock/stub the main and section container components.

Comment: Yes, XPI is a local package. What you described is exactly that! It disassembles and mounts the page, the blinking would be (loading - white screen) between them.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Ah, ok... for the most part that is completely normal. ***BUT*** as a test I commented out the `GuardProvider` and swapped the `GuardedRoute` components for plain `Route` components and tried the same navigations and any "blank" flashes are decreased significantly, to the point I don't think I can see them just eye-balling it. I'll take a deeper dive into this `react-router-guards` package. It seems to be a little older and hasn't been updated in a couple years, maybe it's doing something odd.

Comment: I like to use it because it has a guards middleware, would you have any package tips or a way to do this in an easy way like this library?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS I've always rolled my own custom route components, but I suppose the answer that question depends on what you are using the guards middleware for and what you get out of it. This [issue](https://github.com/Upstatement/react-router-guards/issues/59) seems related to the parent reloading/rerendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Drew answer helped me, but to really solve the problem, I needed to insert something in the `Guard` **loading**, in this case I inserted the `HomePage` itself:

```
<GuardProvider guards={[RequireLoginGuard]} loading={HomePage}>
    <Switch>
      <GuardedRoute exact path='/new' component={HomePage} />
      <GuardedRoute exact path='/stored' component={HomePage} />
      <GuardedRoute path='*' component={() => <Redirect to='/new' />} />
   </Switch>
</GuardProvider>
```